# How to change the date format in Ireport 4.5

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have given text field expression `new.java.util.Date()` and pattern `MMMMM dd, yyyy` as the mentioned format.

The date must display like: `jan 13, 2012` but it's displaying in some other format: `Fri Jan 13 08:30:12 IST 2012`.

So how to print the date in the mentioned format. And one thing in preview the date displays correctly as mentioned but inside my application it displays `Fri Jan 13 08:30:12 IST 2012` format. Is there any way to make it to work properly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy ").format(new Date())
```

Put the above line in text field so you will get your Date format

Answer (score -4):

Use this below method..hope it will help to you

```
public static String getDateTimeForUgcServer(String date)
    {

        SimpleDateFormat intputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date dt = new Date();
        try
        {
            dt = intputFormat.parse(date);
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String str = outputFormat.format(dt);
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. It's not the format that the OP asked for.

Comment: Moreover this is the 3rd question you are posting this exact same **incorrect** answer to.